# What does limit actually mean?

Tags: calculus, limits, nonstandard-analysis, infinitesimals

I have been in a deep confusion for about a month over the topic of limits! According to our book, the limit at $a$ is the value being approached by a function $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $a$.

I have a doubt that in real number line we can never ever reach the closest value to $a$ because always a more closer value will exist.

Now when talking about our methods for calculating limit, what method comes in our mind when we have to calculate where the value approaches? Let's say we have to find what value $f(x)$ approaches when $x$ moves from $[0,a)$.

So we calculate the value of $f(x)$ at $x=0$, say $4$, and then at $x\to a$.

But the problem is that we don't know the value $x\to a$, so we say the value is $a-h$ where $h\to 0$ and calculate the value of $f(a-h)$, say $5-h$.

Now here is where my doubt starts! In the final step we put the value of $h=0$ say in that it is an infinitesimal quantity.

My doubt is that $h$ was tending to $0$ means that it was never equal to zero  maybe it is infinitesimally small, not a stationary value, not an imaginable value, but we know for sure that it is not  equal to $0$. Maybe it is the point closest to zero, but it is not equal to zero and when we use the result $5-h=5$ we are actually making an error which is tending to zero. Maybe the error is very small, but still, there is some error in that we cannot calculate it but we can see that there is this infinitesimal error present.

That means we don't get the exact limiting value or last value of $f(x)$.
 $x$ belongs to $[0,a)$ but a value approximate to infinitesimal? Isn't it right! We get an approximated value?

Comment: The right way to do all this is the "delta-epsilon" approach --- have you seen that? $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ means for every $\epsilon\gt0$ there is a $\delta$ such that if $0\lt|x-a|\lt\delta$ then $|f(x)-L|\lt\epsilon$. It takes a lot of thinking to get your mind around this definition, but in the end it's the only way to clear up all those doubts.

Comment: Alex, I edited your question. Please check to make sure that I didn't change what you are trying to ask.

Comment: It might be gibberish, but is very precisely defined and quite useful gibberish. :)

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: the opinion that epsilon, delta is the *only* way "to clear up those doubts" is just that: an opinion. See my answer below for an alternative.

Comment: @user, maybe. I doubt that infinitesimals have ever cleared up doubts for anyone who hadn't already mastered deltas and epsilons.

Comment: I have some ideas for such an "anyone". How about Kepler? Fermat? Leibniz? Euler? Cauchy? There is much confusion about these "doubts". They typically stem from concern re: their "metaphysical" status as "inassignable" quantities, as Leibniz called them. Yet when one gets around to writing down the objection, one falls back on claims of their allegedly "logically" contradicatory status. This is a serious historical misconception that has been discussed in the recent scholarly literature, some of which was mentioned at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/124998/was-the-early-calculus-inconsistent

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: I would like to add a point about education.  There is no doubt in the mind of any educator who has bothered to look at what is going on in the classroom, e.g. David Tall, that infinitesimals are a much better way of explaining concepts like continuity to students.  This doesn't mean freshmen should get started on ultrafilters. What it does mean is that when the key ideas such as continuity have been explained properly using infinitesimals, the course can branch off either in the epsilon, delta direction, or in the hyperreal direction, depending on the instructor's preference.

Comment: @user, the first textbook using infinitesimals appeared in 1977. I suspect that thousands of educators have looked at what goes on in classrooms in the intervening years, and despite that the proportion of classes using infinitesimals is, well, infinitesimal. The rest would seem to be unconvinced that infinitesimals are a better way.

Comment: @Gerry, See this [1910](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silvanus_P._Thompson) popular textbook exploiting infinitesimals.

Comment: @Gerry, See this [1821](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy#Cours_d.27Analyse) textbook exploiting infinitesimals.

Comment: @Gerry, see this [1696](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analyse_des_Infiniment_Petits_pour_l%27Intelligence_des_Lignes_Courbes) popular textbook exploiting infinitesimals.

Comment: @user, what's your point? Do you know anyone who teaches out of those books? And if the texts have been around since 1696, and there's still hardly anyone using infinitesimals, doesn't it thoroughly refute your assertion that everyone who has looked at what goes on in a classroom thinks infinitesimals are better?

Comment: @Gerry, you referred earlier to "thousands of educators" that looked at the classroom situation.  I don't know if there are that many, but those that have looked at the situation with epsilon, delta teaching have come away dismayed. I can certainly cite many, many studies of this type. This is not the same as saying that it is easy to switch to another system given current institutional constaints and attitudes among the community of teachers.

Comment: @Gerry, as far as the allegedly "infinitesimal" number of classes being taught using infinitesimals, I only have anecdotal evidence but anyway here is the anecdote. On a recent visit to the US I was chatting with a dentist at tea. Predictably, he asked me about my work, and I mentioned that I have been looking at ways of teaching calculus with or without infinitesimals. He was totally surprised and asked: "but how can you teach calculus without infinitesimals?" He was not joking. The private college he went to taught calculus using infinitesimals. This may be the case for many small schools.

Comment: I maintain that everyone who has ever taught calculus has looked at the classroom situation, simply by virtue of having been in the classroom and having done the teaching, and there are certainly thousands of people who have taught calculus, and it's nonsense to say they have all come away dismayed with deltas and epsilons.

Comment: @Gerry, of course, but in the context of our discussion it is clear that I was referring to educators analyzing student performance in such classrooms, rather than what the teachers themselves think of their effectiveness. It is clear that in the education literature the thrust of the comments on epsilon, delta is that it is of very limited success. Mathematicians may or may not agree with this, but I was responding to your comments on educators (meaning education scholars)...

Comment: ...We are getting a bit far from my original comment that it is incorrect to claim that "in the end it's the only way to clear up all those doubts". You may feel that classes using infinitesimals are rare, but you can't deny their success.  See for example the study by [K. Sullivan](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2318657?origin=crossref)

Comment: @user, you can use "educator" to mean "education scholar", I'll use it to mean "educator", that is, someone who educates, that is, someone who gets up in front of a classroom and teaches mathematics.

Comment: @Gerry, fine, we have cleared out that misunderstanding. Incidentally, I got up in front of the classroom and taught calculus using infinitesimals with great success, as described in the response to question 4.1 on page 10 [here](http://www.math.umt.edu/tmme/vol7no1/TMME_vol7no1_2010_article1_pp.3_30.pdf)

Answer (score 14):

Well, in a sense, you're right. When they say that the limit of $f(x)$ at $x=a$ is $L$ it doesn't necessarily mean that $f(a)=L$. Actually, the nice idea behind limits is that you can talk about the limit of a function even if the function is not defined at that value. This is a very powerful idea that later enables us to talk about derivatives as you possibly know.

For example $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$ but the value of $\displaystyle \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is not defined at $x=0$. If you graph it on wolframalpha, you'll see that this means 'as we approach $x=0$ the value of $\displaystyle \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ approaches 1'. *We never claim that these two are equal!* We just claim that the value of $f(x) = \displaystyle \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ can become arbitrarily close to $1$ provided that we let $x$ be close enough to $0$ .

When we say that the limit of $f(x)$ at $x=a$ is $L$, we are claiming that we can make $f(x)$ *arbitrarily* close to $L$ provided that we take $x$ close enough to $a$. That's all.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to respond to OP's comment to the effect that "Maybe the error is very small, but still, there is some error in that we cannot calculate it but we can see that there is this infinitesimal error present." In fact, *discarding* such an infinitesimal remainder is precisely what the limit operation does, in the following sense. In an extended number system, say $E$, including infinitesimals, there is a function from the finite elements of $E$, denoted $E_f$, to $\mathbb{R}$. This function is called the standard part function, and is denoted "st".  Thus we get $$\text{st}:E_f \to \mathbb{R}.$$ For example, attempting to calculate the derivative of $y=x^2$ using the quotient $dy/dx$, one gets $2x+dx$.  To pass from this to the expected formula $2x$, one applies the standard part: $\text{st}(2x+dx)=2x$. More generally, the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ tends to $x_0$ can be defined as $\text{st}(f(x_0+dx))$, whenever the resulting value is independent of the nonzero infinitesimal $dx$ chosen.

The complications in the usual epsilon, delta definitions stem from a preference for working in $\mathbb{R}$ rather than a richer system containing infinitesimals, which is fine. However, the basic point about the limit operation is that it amounts to *discarding* the remaining term you referred to as "error".

So the answer to the *question*: "What does limit actually mean?" is "Taking limit is taking the standard part".

Answer (score 3):

So far as I can understand your question, you need to know that the Real numbers are set up in such a way that limits make sense (defined or constructed - depending on the approach - however they arrive they have a unique set of properties).

The Rational numbers do not behave well when we take limits - $\sqrt 2$ is the usual simple example - we can get as close as we like, but never equal. But $\sqrt 2$ exists as a Real number.

The Real numbers do not have lots of infinitesimals trying to get in the way. As always in mathematics, there are systems which do have infinitesimals, and which approach some of the issues in a different (non-standard) way. But at the heart of working with the Real numbers and with limits is using again and again those special properties of the Real numbers which were designed with limits in mind.

Comment: I think the definition of limit does not need real numbers, it is only certain theorems related to existence of limits which hold true in real number system and not in the rational number system.

Comment: Mark, the OP specifically included the tag [tag:infinitesimals] under his *question*, so slandering infinitesimals is not going to be very helpful for him.

Comment: @MikhailKatz The actual question does not reference infinitesimals in any systematic way which would suggest that they are being deployed in the argument the poster does not understand.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh The point about the Real numbers is that they are constructed so that limits exist. Of course they can be defined for the rationals, but you are always looking over your shoulder wondering whether you have defined a rational number or not.

Comment: @MarkBennet, most questions here are from users who "don't understand" as you put it.  The OP correctly guessed that infinitesimals are behind the definition of limit as proposed by Cauchy, for example; see [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/467519/72694).

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure that I understand exactly what you are asking.

However, maybe the following might aide to your understanding. To truely understand limit you might want to look at the definition. That is:
$$
\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L
$$
means that

> for all $\epsilon >0$ there is some $\delta >0$ such that if $0<\lvert
>  x-a\rvert < \delta$ then $\lvert f(x) - L\rvert < \epsilon$.

Now this might look intimidating, and in many ways it is. It will take some time to get your head wrapped around the definition, but if you are willing to do some work, I think that you can do it.

That said, while we have the definition to that tell us exactly what a limit is, there are ways to *think* about a limit. This "ways of thinking about a limit" can be helpful in getting an idea/picture of what limit means.

That $f(x)$ approaches $L$ as $x$ approaches $a$ means that we can make the values of $f(x)$ as close to $L$ as we would like by making $x$ as *close enough* to $a$.

You write that:

> So we calculate value of $f(x)$ at $x=0,$ say $4$, and then at $x\to a$.

You also  write

> I have a doubt that in real number line we can never ever reach the
>   closest value to a because always a more closer value will exist.

Note that we are not actually calculating the value of $f(x)$ at $x\to a$. That doesn't make sense. That $f(x)$ approaches $L$ as $x$ approaches $a$ doesn't mean that we can evaluate $f$ at some number and then get $L$. The values of $f(x)$ do not need to ever equal $L$. We are not *evaluating* $f$ at some "infinitesimal quantity".

Example: Consider the function $f(x) = x+7$. Then we obviously have that 
$$
\lim_{x\to 1} f(x) = 8.
$$
In this example we even have that $f(1) =8$, but again this is irrelevant for finding the limit. It should be clear that when $x$ is very close to $a$ then $x + 7$ is very close to $8$.

Example: No consider this function:
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{ if } x = 1 \\ x + 7& \text{ if } x \neq 1 \end{cases}.
$$
Now we have that $g(1) = 0$, but we still have that
$$
\lim_{x\to 1} g(x) = 8.
$$
As $x$ approaches $1$ we don't have $x$ ever equal to $1$. So, wince $x$ is never equal to $1$ we can work with the expression $x+7$ for $g(x)$. So again 
$$
\lim_{x\to 1} g(x) = 8.
$$
Example: One more example woulf be to consider the function
$$
h(x) = 7.
$$
This is the constant function that is equal to $7$ for all $x$. So what is the limit 
$$
\lim_{x\to 1} h(x)?
$$
It is $7$ because we can make the values of $h(x)$ as close to $7$ as we want by making $x$ close enough to $1$. If you, for example, wanted the values of $h(x)$ to be with in $0.001$ (so here $\epsilon = 0.001$ in the definition) of $7$, you can take any tolerance for $x$ because $h$ is always equal to $7$.

Comment: The $\epsilon$-$\delta$ limit definition *I* know does not have the $0<$ part. Especially, the limit $\lim_{x\to 1}g(x)$ does not exist for the definition I know. (BTW, even with your definition it would be $2$, not $8$.)

Comment: @celtschk: Thanks for catching the typo in $g(x)$. The limit $\lim_{x\to 1} g(x)$ does indeed exist. Note that a function $f$ doesn't have to be defined at $a$ for us to talk about the limit of $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$. So we should have the $<0$ part. This is a common thing to forget though. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit#Precise_statement

Comment: If $g$ were *not* defined at $x=1$, then the limit would certainly exist. But the point is that you $did$ define $g$ at point $x=1$. Now with the definition you gave (with $0<$) the limit indeed exists, but with the definition *I* know it wouldn't. Note that the limit would also exist if $g(x)$ were undefined for all points in $\{1+1/n: n\in \mathbb N\}$, despite the fact that your definition doesn't exclude those points. This is because the condition of course has to be fulfilled only in the domain of $g$ (while the limit is defined on the closure of the domain).

Comment: Again, you might want to look up the definition elsewhere. Note that if you don't have the $<0$ part, then you would require that $f(a) = L$. This is true if $f$ is continuous at $a$. However, we don't need $f$ to be continuous at $a$ for the limit to exist.

Comment: Continuous *or not defined.*

Comment: @celtschk: I don't understand. It is common to talk about a function as not being continuous at a point where it is not defined.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9884/discussion-between-thomas-and-celtschk)

Comment: Sorry, I can't go to chat from here (a technical problem); so that will have to wait until I'm at home (in at latest two hours).

Comment: @celtschk: Ok, talk to you later.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a simple discontinuous example will enlight you. Let $f(x) = 0$ if $x \leq 0$, $1$ if $x> 0$. I want to compute the right limit, that is $\lim_{x\to0,x>0} f(x)$.

In this case you are right, there is a difference between $f(0)=0$ and $f(\text{small quantity})=1$. The infinitesimal error induces a non infinitesimal difference in the values.

However this won't happen when the function is continuous. By definition, continuity means that f(x) equal to its limit $\lim_{dx\to0} f(x+dx)$ at every point. In this case, you can neglect the infinitesimal $dx$ and write $f(x) = \lim_{dx\to 0} f(x+dx)$.

The real issue here is that you would use continuity to prove something on the limits, while this limit is required to prove continuity itself. There exists a true mathematical definition of limits, but it seems out of the scope of your current grade.

The real definition of limit is "you can get as close as you like to the limit". Hence $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} = l$ actually means
$\forall \epsilon, \exists \eta / \forall x, d(x,x_0) < \eta \Rightarrow d(l,f(x_0)) < \epsilon$, where d is some distance. The $\epsilon$ formalizes the "as close as you like' .I am afraid you can't do clean maths on limits without this definition

Answer (score 0):

I would like to respond more directly to the following comment of the OP:

*Now here is were my doubt starts! In the final step we put the value of h=0  say in that it is infinitesimal quantity.*

I would say that the point is *not* to set $h$ equal to zero, but rather to *discard* it at the end of the calculation. Thus, the limit can be defined as follows: (1) one starts with an infinitesimal increment, and then (2) one "rounds off the value of the function to the nearest real number". Fermat, Leibniz, and others always chose their language carefully so as *not* to imply that one sets the increment equal to zero.  Some relevant literature can be found [here](http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~katzmik/infinitesimals.html).